# What reads thermal sensors

Tags: 16.04, power-management

I’m using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I’m learning it (and GNU/Linux in general). Trying to find out what is really responsible for reading motherboard and CPU thermal sensors in Ubuntu 16.04? What is responsible for power management of my desktop? Is it only acpid? Or is it something else or more?

Comment: Are you looking for how the hardware works, or how to manage the power consumption of the computer?

Comment: Your questions seem very broad and I think are unlikely to get answers you are looking for. I would suggest you focus on one specific topic, such as power management, and read into that.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly then

```
sudo sensors-detect
```

will take you through a process to detect all (most of) the thermal sensors on your motherboard, CPU and GPU etc. (please the warnings in the manual).  'sensors-detect' may also recommend that you install additional modules to your kernel that your computer needs to read certain system sensors.

To install 'sensors' and 'sensors-detect' you may need to `sudo apt install lm-sensors`

You can then read the temperatures with:

```
sensors
```